# rails-api: associating metadata from a second join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I have, at the high level, `Recipe`, `Skill`, and `User`, with join tables of `RecipeSkill` and `UserSkill`.

When returning skills for a given recipe, I'd like to know what skills for that recipe the user has already learned. You can see some example JSON below.

I'm not really even sure the best way to have phrased this question, since I just feel lost about how to tackle this problem. I'm sure I could hack something together, but it seems like a fairly common case where there must be some preexisting conventions.

Here are my models and my `RecipeSerializer`:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :recipe_skills
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_skills
  has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_skills
end

class RecipeSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :skill
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
  # attributes :id, :user_id, :skill_id, :strength, :capacity, :learned
end

class RecipeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids, include: true

  has_many :skills

  attributes :id, :title
end
```

And here's some example JSON:

```
{
  "skills": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Grilling Chicken",
      "earned": true
    }
  ]
  "recipe": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Roasted Potatoes",
    "skill_ids": [
      1
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Skill` serializer, perhaps, add a method that figures whether the user has that skill or not. Assuming that if `user.skills` contain skills they've learned:

```
class SkillSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :earned, # :id, :name, etc

  def earned
    scope.skills.include? object  
  end
end
```

Scope is the user you're representing. See the [docs here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#customizing-scope).

I think there are probably some performance issues here, but hopefully it can put you in the right direction.

Comment: My main concern really is the performance issues. I was hoping there may be a better way.

Comment: Perhaps a dedicated method on user like user.earned_skill?(skill) could do some lightweight memoization/caching. I'm sure you could get that to work with only one DB query.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I extracted everything out into a `UserSkillsCache` object, as well, and memoized there. Thanks!